# admin notice display in woocommerce page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to display the wordpress admin notice in admin panel woocommerce product add new page every time

```
add_action('admin_notices', check_https); 

function check_https()
{
    echo '<div class="notice notice-error">You need to enable SSL</div>';

}
```

Comment: please elaborate more.... as per the code... notification is showing in every page in admin panel right ?

Comment: @Alice Yes notification is showing all pages but i need only product add new page.